# Can I get remove of the 'execution' parameter from GET?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, spring-webflow

I use to Spring Webflow. Can I get remove of the 'execution' parameter from GET?

For example:

http://localhost:8090/myapp/account/register.do?**execution=e1s2**

http://localhost:8090/myapp/account/register.do?**execution=e2s12**

http://localhost:8090/myapp/account/register.do?**execution=e3s2**

Comment: Is it really bookmarkable? My understanding is that the flow execution is tied to the session, so once the session expires the flow will no longer be accessible thereby breaking the user's bookmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by setting `always-redirect-on-pause` attribute of flow executor to `false`, but it is not recommended - `execution` parameter causes that url is **stateful** and **bookmarkable**.

```
<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" >
    ...
    <webflow:flow-execution-attributes>
        <!-- without execution param -->
        <webflow:always-redirect-on-pause value="false"/>
    </webflow:flow-execution-attributes>
</webflow:flow-executor>
```

This url may be useful: [http://www.ervacon.com/products/swf/tips/tip4.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20070219094813/http://www.ervacon.com/products/swf/tips/tip4.html)

Comment: Thanks dude helped a lot.