# Spring Web-Flow Keeps Replacing Get Request Parameters With its Execution Parameter

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

i am programming in a framework that uses spring web-flow and JSF. 
I have to create a rest service that acts on get requests. but the problem is that spring web-flow replace my request parameters with its own "execution parameter" for example the url that i need is : `http://localhost:8080/app/rg/restService?id=ca9761e3-90d1-40ca-b160-5c704b2ac982` but web-flow changes this url to `http://localhost:8080/app/rg/restService?execution=e4s1` . 
by the way, there is a solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594137/can-i-get-remove-of-the-execution-parameter-from-get) but i can not use that.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't use Web Flow for the REST service. Web Flow is for stateful "flows" through multiple steps. Just use JAX-RS or Spring MVC for the RESTful service.

Comment: web-flow is already in use in my framework i can not eliminate it. i managed to go around it by url's like http://localhost:8080/app/rg/restService#{id=ca9761e3-90d1-40ca-b160-5c704b2ac982}

Comment: That's what I meant. Not eliminating it for where you really need to use it, just not using it for this case. As you describe, you can mix Web Flow with other technologies.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with dbreaux, you should create another Dispatcher Servlet specifically for your REST services and give it a different mapping so that one does not interfere with the other. You can still reuse your existing beans if they are declared in the parent context.